# How to show rounded numbers on a form (to 2 decimal places), but still let people edit and submit the full numbers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, rounding

I have a form on my MVC3 site (I also use EF, but it's not relevant). Now, this form consists of multiple input boxes in which users provide some numbers (decimal).
The request from the user is to use full number in the calculations and when storing, but when we show them to the user they should be rounded to 2 decimals.

As I imagine it: the user sees a rounded number in an input box, but as soon as the box gets focus, full number is shown. Also when the form is submitted - the full numbers are sent to the server. Is there anything ready to achieve that? If not, do you have suggestions on how to make it and make it generic? I can only think os some JS lib, but let's hear your ideas...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this will be JS. Use a rounded number in value. Save actual number in a hidden. Use Jquery `on focus` event and fill input with hidden. The tricky part is when focus is regained your value will be over-written again if you're not careful. not easy to achieve but do-able.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two fileds somthing like this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RealValue, new {id = "realValue"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DisplayValue, new {id = "dispValue"})
```

and in a script part to make the logic

```
$('#dispValue').focus(function() { $(this).val($('#realValue').val())});
$('#dispValue').focusout(function() { $('realValue').val($(this).val()); $(this).val($(this).val().toFixed(2))})
```

And the last thing you shoud do is to send from the controller the display value with two decimal.

Comment: with an update before apply toFixed(2) yo have to parse to float

Comment: parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2)

Comment: That would mean that my model has two separate values (real and display) for the same thing. I want to avoid that. I think it's possible to do it with just one and also keep it nice and simple. I will post my solution when I start on this problem. For now I'm busy with something else.

Comment: you can leave the display model and use yust @Html.TextBox("dispValue") i can't see another solution. If you find one please post it

Comment: The other solution would be to have full numbers in the viewmodel and only use javascript to round and swap visible values in the textbox and hidden field for the same value. Then I am not sure what happens if we send both values to the action. Maybe I could strip the rounded values with javascript and not send them (if necessary) - I am posting with AJAX, so some additional code would not be a problem. These are just ideas...